# Override default expand behaviour on Timeline group click

Tags: vis.js, timeline.js

I'm trying to find a way to override the default expand/collapse behaviour when clicking on a Group element in a VisJS Timeline.

I'd like to allow other actions from the group contents, and invoke the expand/collapse action programmatically from somewhere else in the UI.

I'm been looking into the code in the **v4.21**, but I don't seem to find a way to override the **_onGroupClick** on the **ItemSet**.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this in the most elegant way? (trying to avoid monkey patching)

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for the same solution, and I found the solution just [here](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3333#issuecomment-345449503)

In my case, I just use the 'off' to disconnect the toggle from the general first cell of each row. Then I manually change the `showNested` property of the groups and call `setGroups` to open, in this way I can show the action exactly in the item I want not in the whole cell.

Comment: Gracias Roberto! I forgot to reference the github discussions which indeed gives some pointers to a possible solution. Thanks!